# Customize indentation width in haskell-indentation mode

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

I am currently using Emacs as my primary IDE for developing Haskell code and I am really satisfied so far. But at the moment I can't figure out one little detail, namely how to customize the indentation width to be 4 instead of 2.

Currently I have turned on the `haskell-indentation` in `haskell-mode`, but I can't figure out what variable I have to set to customize the indentation width.
So far I have tried to set `'(haskell-indent-spaces 4)` but this doesn't seem to have any effect at all...

Thx in advance for any help!

Comment: Based on [the source](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/haskell-indentation.el) it looks like `2` is hardcoded in the file.

Comment: @gallais Thx for your reply. I guess for the time being, I have to edit the source code directly then. Can you post this as an answer, so that I can acccept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the source](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/blob/master/haskell-indentation.el) of `haskell-indentation`, it looks like `2` is hardcoded in the file so you'll have to edit it manually.

Answer (score 6):

`haskell-indentation-mode` offers a couple of knobs you can turn to customize indentation offsets:

```
haskell-indentation-layout-offset
haskell-indentation-starter-offset
haskell-indentation-left-offset
haskell-indentation-ifte-offset
haskell-indentation-where-pre-offset
haskell-indentation-where-post-offset
```

All of those are customization variables so you can do `M-x customize-option RET` and customize any of those, or if you prefer programatically:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; Customization related to indentation.
 '(haskell-indentation-layout-offset 4)
 '(haskell-indentation-starter-offset 4)
 '(haskell-indentation-left-offset 4)
 '(haskell-indentation-where-pre-offset 4)
 '(haskell-indentation-where-post-offset 4)
 )
```

Comment: Worked great for me! I adjusted haskell-indentation-where-pre-offset and haskell-indentation-where-post-offset to 2 though, to achieve slightly different behaviour for where, but this is certainly the best solution I found.